# Can't change drawerWidth on paper-drawer-panel Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer-1.0

It's pretty basic but i don't know if it's a bug or i'm wrong with something.
I cant change the width of the drawer in the paper-drawer-panel. In the documentation page specify to add the property drawerWith.
Here is some code:

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
<template>
<style>
:host {
display: block;
}
</style>

<paper-drawer-panel drawerWidth="300px">
<!--  Nav Bar -->
<section drawer>
<!-- Logo -->
<div id="logoContainer">
<img id="logo" src="../img/logo.png">
</div>
</section>

<!--  Content  -->
<paper-header-panel main>
<paper-toolbar>
<paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
<div class="flex">My App</div>
</paper-toolbar>
</paper-header-panel>

</paper-drawer-panel>

</template>

<script>
// element registration
Polymer({
is: "my-app",

});
</script>

</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
<paper-drawer-panel drawer-width="300px">
```

[Here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping) you can find the documentation that talks about it.

> Attribute names with dashes are converted to camelCase property names by capitalizing the character following each dash, then removing the dashes. For example, the attribute first-name maps to firstName.

So, in documentation says `drawerWidth` when you use it in your elements must be: `drawer-width`